# Switch statement javascript Image and Text

Tags: javascript, html

Edit: as I was posting this code and formatting it for the site, It changed to just always showing only "this is the text for image1", but not working as I inteded it to.

I have 1 picture showing.
I have a function to change that image between 2 images.

I simply want the bottom of the picture to have the text corresponding to the picture. 
function diffImage is working fine.
function changeStyle is not..
It is currently saying : Undefined as the text.

Example 
Pic1
text for 1.jpg

```js
function diffImage(img) {
  if (img.src.match("1.jpg")) img.src = "2.jpg";
  else img.src = "1.jpg";
}

function changeStyle() {
  var text001;
  var pic = document.getElementById("image1");

  switch (pic) {
    case image1:
      text001 = "this is the text for image1 ";
      break;
    case image2:
      text001 = " this is the text for image2";
      break;
  }
  document.getElementById("imgMessage").innerHTML = text001;
}
```

```html
<img src="1.jpg" id="image1" onclick=diffImage(this) class="image1" />
<p id="imgMessage"></p>
<button onclick="changeStyle()"> Change</button>
<img src="2.jpg" id="image2" style="display:none" />
```

Comment: When I click on the button I get the text "This is the text for image1".

Comment: What do you mean  by "the text corresponding to the picture"? Maybe you should be using `switch(pic.getAttribute("src"))` to get the src URL?

Comment: yes sorry, I edited the op. It is just not working as it always says text for image 1, and it never changes to text for image 2.

Comment: It's still not clear what you're trying to test in the `switch()` statement. What is it supposed to use to decide which message to show?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `textOO1` never gets set due to the variables `image1` and `image2` don't exist. None of the cases in your switch statement are getting called.

Comment: Element IDs automatically become global variables. So `image1` is the same as `document.getElementById('image1')`.

Comment: In the question he is wondering why it is undefined, but the snippet he posted actually sets it to a value.  I am confused as to what the question is here.

Comment: Yes, there's obviously more to the problem than what he posted.

Comment: @skelletor  yes sorry I edited the OP. it is showing only the value of image 1. And it never changes to image 2 text. I was having difficulty formatting it properly to post for some reason, and i changed something in the process, sorry. Nonetheless my code isnt working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your case statements to:

`case "image1"` and `case "image2"` - remember, they are strings. You're using them as variables.

Comment: `pic` is a DOM element, why would he compare it to strings?

Answer (score 0):

In `diffImage`, you just changed `src` not `id`, but in `changeStyle` you are trying to find the image by `id`, so `pic` will always be `image1`, hence the text won't change.

```js
      function diffImage(img){
        if(img.id.match("image1")) {
          document.getElementById("image1").style ="display: none";
          document.getElementById("image2").style ="display: block";
        } else {
        document.getElementById("image1").style ="display: block";
        document.getElementById("image2").style ="display: none";
      }
      }

      function changeStyle(){

        var text001;
        var pic =document.getElementById("image1").style.display;

        switch(pic){
          case "block":
            text001 = "this is the text for image1 ";
            break;
          case "none":
            text001 = " this is the text for image2";
            break;
          }
          document.getElementById("imgMessage").innerHTML = text001;
        }
```

```html
    <img src="img/img.jpg"  id="image1" onclick=diffImage(this) style="display:block" class ="image1"/>
    <img src="img/img2.jpg" id="image2" onclick=diffImage(this) style="display:none"/>
    <p id = "imgMessage"></p>
    <button onclick = "changeStyle()"> Change</button>
```

Comment: Can you make your answer an executable snippet, like in the question?

Comment: Ahhh, this makes sense. Thanks !